# What is this redirection called and how can it be setup for an ASP based site?

Tags: asp.net, url, redirect

Does this redirection method have a specific name, and how do I set it up for an ASP based site?
`http://www.example.com/?URL=www.redirecteddomain.com`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in that case, it not really the web server, but simply your code that can do this.

so, if you web page was:

```
http://localhost/MyJumpPage.aspx?URL=www.google.com
```

So, in your code, all you have to do is grab that 1st parameter, and then run code to jump/navigate to that page.

EG:

```
string strURL = "";

strURL = Request.QueryString("URL");

Response.Redirect("http://" + strURL);
```

So, the code behind a button, or even on page load can simply pull the query value from the url string, and then jump to that URL.